# Swift: can't get NSDate dateFormatter right

Tags: ios, date, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

DateFormatter is acting funny to me:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM'/'DD'/'YYYY"
var dateString = "09/28/1989"
var date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
println(date)
```

Returns:

> "Optional(1988-12-24 13:00:00 +0000)"

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: try this in Swift 3 : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46027060/3400991

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your date formatter is a bit off. `"MM'/'DD'/'YYYY"` reads `"Padded month / day of the year (not month) / year of the current week (so Jan 1-6 could overlap and add side-effects)"`

I'm guessing that what you're aiming for is `"MM'/'dd'/'yyyy"`, which reads `"Padded month / padded day of month / year"`

For reference, here's the currently-used [Unicode Technical Standard](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) that Apple documents as their standard for iOS 7+ and OSX 10.9+ [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html)

Comment: FYI - the use of `'` around the `/` are not needed. You only need to quote letters that you want to be treated as literals instead of format specifiers.